# Speech recognition api in a background agents on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

My question -I want to use speech recognition API that work when application is in background. Is it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the speech APIs aren't in the list of [Unsupported APIs for background agents for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) this does surprise me.

I suspect that you are actually trying to have an application which is always listening in the background but this is not what a background agent will do. At best it will only run periodically (approx. 25 seconds every 30 mins) and I assume that's not what you want.

There is no way to create an app that is always running in the background. Regardless of whether it is doing speech recognition.

Answer (score 0):

I have never actually tried this, but I'd say I doubt that it is possible for the following reasons.

1) Background tasks run for a limited time period at a specific interval.  The chances of the agent being active when you want it to be are very slight.
2) How would you notify your agent that you want to give it voice input if your UI is not running?

Comment: Actually I require if some one speck dictation like "Help"(content related to my app) then it is automatically recognize by app when app in background.

Comment: My question would be (if it were possible, but I think it is not) how would the system know that you saying "help" relates to your app and not some other app installed, or the system itself?  I think you are going to have to accept it isn't possible and just use voice commands within your app when it is in the foreground